# How to chroot into busybox environment?

Tags: chroot, busybox

I have a filesystem build with buildroot, to compile code for a device using a old kernel and uClibc.

Now I want to `chroot` into the fs. The problem is, I don't have `/bin/bash`, just `/bin/busybox`.
 How do I say chroot to use `busybox ash` instead?

I already tried to create a link to `busybox ash`, but chroot still says `failed to run command /bin/bash. no such file or directory`.

Answer (score 5):

```
chroot /path/to/fs /bin/ash
```

See the `chroot` man page for details.

Comment: this doesn't work, i just have busybox in my /bin/ directory.

Comment: You said that you had a link `ash -> busybox`. Anyway, just run `chroot /path/to/fs /bin/busybox ash` then.

Answer (score 0):

Busybox does not include a ldd script. Instead you can run it like this.

```
LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /bin/busybox
            libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0xb6ece000)
            libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb6d8c000)
            /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6ef2000)
```

As you can see busybox depends on a couple of libraries in this case. 
So I created a directory structure like below and was able to run ls command.

```
# pwd
/home/<jail>

# ls -R
.:
bin   lib   sbin

./bin:
busybox  login    ls       sh

./lib:
ld-linux-armhf.so.3  libc.so.6            libresolv.so.2

...
# chroot /home/<jail>/ ls
bin   lib   sbin
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to 'ldd busybox' and copy over the shared libs to which it links into the chroot.  Use 'cp -L src dst' on the libs because they are usually simlinked.

Comment: Busybox is usually statically linked to avoid this.